# Translation to Latin of "everything is revenge"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check

I'm trying to translate a phrase. I'm trying to say "everything is (part of) revenge", as in "every action is an act of revenge against the ones that tried to break you". Sorry if it's not too clear English is not my first language. So far I've come up *omnia ultio*, but a friend (that is somewhat better at Latin) said that this sounds more like "everybody's revenge".

Answer (score 2):

*Ultio* is indeed good for "revenge".
The wordings that more literally match "everything is revenge" sound a little awkward to me, so I suggest instead:

> *Nihil nisi ultio.*
>   Nothing but revenge.

This sounds like proper Latin and seems to get the same message across.
You can also add a verb to both languages (or just English and leave it implicit in Latin):

> *Nihil est nisi ultio.*
>   There is nothing but revenge.